# How to minimize the image to set on mobile

Tags: html, css, image-rendering

I using below URL to set the background image:

https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Untitled-design-2.png

```html
body { background-image: url("https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Untitled-design-2.png"); 
background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #3A3F50;
}
```

With this i am able to set the background correctly in the browser but the same screen if i see in mobile  i am not able to see the full image since it is not setting or rendering based on the screen size.

Is there a way to display the same image in browser and mobile or can i minimize the above image to certain dimension and display on mobile ?

Comment: you want the image to fit a mobile screen 100% or half, i've seen your image it's only about quarter of the screen?

Comment: Yes i want fit 100% on mobile screen and as well on browser

Comment: @Abdul Azeez you can check my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to scale both up and down on mobile screens, set the `css` width property to `100%` and `height` to auto:

```css
.image_class {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you want an image to scale down if it has to, but never scale up to be larger than its original size, use `max-width: 100%`:

```css
.image_name {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you want to restrict a responsive image to a maximum size, use the max-width property, with a pixel value of your choice:

```css
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

in your case, your image seems to be within the body tag, in the first case

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Untitled-design-2.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #3a3f50;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

this will span the image across the entire page, but with your image `https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Untitled-design-2.png` it seems that the dimensions are smaller hence the image might become blurry but nevertheless, on a mobile device it will resize according to the viewport
**in the second scenario**, you can have something like this

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Untitled-design-2.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #3a3f50;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

the image will take 100% width both on large and small screens, meaning that on a mobile device the image will resize to 100% of the container

also you can use `viewport` height and widths, this will ensure that the image spans the whole page depending on your width and height value, you can also check the [mobile viewports](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/experiences/vec/mobile-viewports.html) to see how you can set dimensions for mobile screens
i hope this helps

Comment: i am so sorry sir @codefather, i am not html css guy if you dont mind can you please help me out where to add, I want the same image to be set both in broswer and mobile

Answer (score 1):

If percentage(%) is not working, you can use vh(view port height) and vw(view port width) to set background size

```css
body {
 background-image: url("https://postcron.com/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Untitled-design-2.png");
 background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

you can preview [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/s3e1xa6z/)